# Back to before the beans, My Caffeine Farm

Tags: beans, growing

I am new when it comes to designer coffee, but I am very good with plants and can grow almost anything.

I would like to know if there is something I can do to the soil or plant to boost the caffeine value of my beans?

Thanks

Comment: From what I know elevation, climate, variety, and processing effect the taste and caffeine content. Maybe try and mimic the climate of where that variety is typically grow to achieve a decent taste and caffeine content. Its typically hard to get all the variable right without living within the "coffee belt" or in a suitable climate. Hence why nearly all coffee is imported if you live outside of these regions. Most notable Columbia, Peru, Kenya, Ethiopia, Rwandan, Costa Rica, Brazil, etc.

Comment: Regions have such an impact on taste profile that it is one of the more popular ways to categorize bean varieties. So its likely that you live in a less than optimal climate for cultivating coffee, unless you live in a region that exports coffee, or you have a way to mimic the climate the bean variety is commonly grown in.

Answer (score 1):

The caffeine content of your coffee will depend on the variety, the method of extraction and the roast of your beans.

You can see on this [paper about caffeine contents of turkish coffee](http://journals.ju.edu.jo/DirasatHum/article/viewFile/1805/1793) on table 7, that unroasted coffee releases almost no caffeine, while dark roast gives the best release.

This [article](http://www.coffeedetective.com/caffeine-in-coffee.html) also has an interesting comparison on the caffeine content of different varieties.

I've talked to coffee producers who've told me that Geisha has 35% less caffeine than tipica, and there is a variety of Laurina that has only 25% of the caffeine found in tipica. 
I haven't been able to find data on this, but I did find a little [data](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11711066) that points to it being in the right neigboardhood.